# Android: Locate cursor in multi-textbox from java code

Tags: java, android

Image related to the Problem: [Multi-Textboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSvsT.png)

Situation:There are two textboxes. There is one 'Speak Now' imageButton. Whenever I touch 'Speak Now' button, I wish my text would be written to the textbox where cursor is blinking.

I did this easily for one textbox since I didn't have to locate the cursor blink:

```
if(editText.length()==0)
    {
        editText.setText(result.get(0));
    }
```

But for two text boxes - I am stuck! Following is code for only one text box.

```
public void onActivityResult(int request_code, int result_code, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(request_code, result_code, intent);
        switch (request_code) {
            case 100:
                if (result_code == RESULT_OK && intent != null) {
                    ArrayList<String> result = intent.getStringArrayListExtra
                       (RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                       //todo:get location of cursor


                    if (editText.length() == 0) {
                        editText.setText(result.get(0));
                    } else {
                                editText.setText(concatenateText
                                    (editText.getText().toString(),
                                        result.get(0)));
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

If cursor is at upper textBox then setText in textbox_up else setText in textbox_down. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What you may need to do is declare a Class global variable of whatever data type you like so as to distinguish which TextBox last had focus (remember, your button selection will take the focus away). In a **focusLost()** event for ***each*** TextBox set a value to this global variable so as to know which TextBox had last focus. Now in your **actionPerformed** event (or whatever event you're using) for your Button you can easily determine which TextBox last had focus by reading what is contained within your class global variable.

Comment: I added ensuing line of code, and then it worked as wished: if(editTextTopic.hasFocus()){
                        if(editTextTopic.length()==0){
                            editTextTopic.setText(result.get(0));
                        }
                        else{
                            editTextTopic.setText(concatenateText(editTextTopic.getText().toString(),
                                    result.get(0)));
                        }
It was helpful. Thanx. :)